# About a chat client-server program in java

Tags: java, client-server, chat

I made a client-server chat that uses a postgresql database to store the users. The server uses comunication protocols designed by me to allow the comunication process and everything works fine. The problem is, the user needs to click on a button in order to open the chat window when he gets the message, otherwise he can't read the incoming message. I would like to program a msn-like service where a window opens when you get a message if the window is not already open and if it's open just show the message in that same window. I can't seem to find a way to do it and any help I can get would really be apreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to give a whole lot more detail if you're expecting a useful answer. What sort of technologies are we talking? RCP? Swing? What have you tried so far and what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you may want to take a look at. First is Java integration with Windows System tray. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/

The other is to run a "listener" in the background perhaps as a Windows service.
This service listens for messages and pops them into a window. The window can be dismissed (hidden) without stopping the service. http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32068